# Help reading a rekordbox edb file

Tags: file-format

My questions is similar to this, albeit slightly different: [Help reversing a EDB database file for Pioneers Rekordbox software](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/help-reversing-a-edb-database-file-for-pioneers-rekordbox-software/32231#32231)

The rekordbox 5 library export produces a 'datafile.edb' file with useful meta data for tracks. I'd like to read that file to extract the meta data (note I'm not interested in parsing the other files that the OP in the linked question mentions).

As suggested in that question, I have attempted to open the 'datafile.edb' file with libesedb however I get an error:

```
>>> import pyesedb
>>> file_object = open('datafile.edb')
>>> esedb_file = pyesedb.file()
>>> esedb_file.open_file_object(file_object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: pyesedb_file_open_file_object: unable to open file.
```

Has anyone had any success reading this file? If anyone has any experience or suggestions then I can email you an example datafile.edb which I'd like to parse.

Comment: Did you try to open the file as open('datafile.edb', **"rb"**) ?